# About Problems Migrating Data From Magento 1.9.2.1 to Magento 2.2 .6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, data-migration

Magento 1.9.2.1 to Magento 2.2.6 encountered an error with EAV during the data migration process.

The error is as follows.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 151 in /var/www/html/tertiary/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 813
```

I added the code for the file below.

vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml

```
<groups xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../groups.xsd">
    <group name="ignore">
        <attribute type="catalog_category">sw_product_attribute_tab_2</attribute>
    </group>
    <group name="frontend_input_empty_allowed">
...
    </group>
</groups>
```

Repeated migration after rebuilding Magento 1.9.2.1 and Magento 2.2.6 databases from dump resulted in the same error.

The configuration file is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    ....
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="m1_db" user="magento_user" password="magento" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="m2_db" user="magento_user" password="magento" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <crypt_key>5e9bf8abe895328d0853754072a3328f</crypt_key>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.1/map.xml</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.2.1</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
    </options>
</config>
```

The error log is shown below.

```
[2019-07-30 07:53:20][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:53:20][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:53:20][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:53:21][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:53:21][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:53:21][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed
[2019-07-30 07:54:43][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:45][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:45][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:45][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:47][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:47][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:47][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:48][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:48][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:48][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:48][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:48][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 07:54:49][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:52][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 07:57:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 07:58:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:09:52][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:09:52][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:09:52][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:09:53][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:09:53][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:09:53][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed
[2019-07-30 08:10:05][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:06][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:09][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 08:10:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:50][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:50][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:50][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:50][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 08:41:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:09][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:09][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:09][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:10][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:10][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:10][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed
[2019-07-30 09:31:38][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:42][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:42][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:42][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:42][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:42][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:43][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:43][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:43][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 09:31:44][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:37][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:37][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:37][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:38][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:38][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:38][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed
[2019-07-30 09:57:54][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:58][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 09:57:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 09:58:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:21][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:21][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:21][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:22][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:23][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:23][INFO][mode: settings][stage: volume check][step: Stores Step]: Migration completed
[2019-07-30 10:43:36][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:37][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:40][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 10:43:41][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:05][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:07][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:07][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:07][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 11:18:11][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:52][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:52][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:52][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:52][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2019-07-30 11:21:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2019-07-30 11:22:00][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
```

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: in fresh database ??

Comment: Rebuilt database from dump file. And we repeated the data migration. The same error was output.

Comment: Rebuilt database from dump file ??? please explain breifly

Comment: Restored the database to its pre-migration state.

Comment: how can you restored database ?

Comment: And After change in eav-attribute-groups.xml  this file you can change also in config.xml file

Comment: Added the contents of the configuration file.

Comment: how can you restored database ?

Comment: mysql -u magento_user -p m2_db < /var/www/html/magento_project/m2_db_backup.sql

Comment: is this m2_db_backup.sql  database is fresh ?

Comment: Of course. State before data migration.

Comment: check migration.log

Comment: Added error log.

Comment: please clear log and try migration and check log

Comment: I see. You must restore the database. It will take some time until the next reply. Also, I will revise the content of the post, so I would appreciate it if you could check it at that time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96822/discussion-between-rk-rathod-and-mr-hironobu).